# Expand/Collapse List in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

What I want to achieve is to have a list of element (div or span) where every item can be expanded and collapsed via click. Let's take in example the following image:
[image: Example]
By default, the list will look as on the left: when I click on an item (in this example item2), that item will expand to show more info and, in case another item was expanded, that other item will collapse.. Meaning that I can have one item expanded at most.

I managed to do this already, but I want the item to expand/collapse smoothly, meaning with some animation.. Using JQuery I would go with some slideUp and SlideDown, but in REACT I haven't figured out how to do (I shouldn't manipulate the DOM like I would to in JS vanilla and Jquery).. I've seen 'React-Transition-Group' module but I didn't manage to do this with that module.

Comment: Use a CSS animation.

Comment: Tried http://react-animations.herokuapp.com/ ?

Comment: @Andy: So far my current solution is using CSS Transition, which is not that good because I have to use max-height property when item will have different hegiht.. I'm gonna try something with CSS animation too though |||| G_S: I think it's the same as Andy suggested, but more "module-oriented" (dunno if that word exists eheh)